# Can "cinema" work as a collective noun?

Tags: nouns, figures-of-speech, collective-nouns

> The local cinema do not even consider screening this movie.

In the above sentence, "cinema" is employed to denote one or more of the staff who determine the programme.

My question is, does it work?

The doubt is whether the sentence sounds odd in the desired meaning. I rather think it does, and have failed to find analogous examples lying around.

I am using the term *collective noun* for lack of a better classification. If acceptable at all, one might argue for a *synecdoche* or a [*deferred reference*](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Deferred_reference) in order to determine the figure of speech, but I am not quite sure about the classification of the noun.

Comment: This could likely work in BrE, but AmE would prefer singular agreement.

Comment: In British English I might say, 'The local cinema doesn't even consider screening this movie.' However I would be more likely to say, 'They don't even consider screening this movie at the local cinema.'

Comment: My first guess upon reading that is that you meant "local cinema" as the 'local cinema scene', i.e. a collective noun for the various cinemas and associated people, periodicals, etc.

So, I'd avoid the usage simply because of the ambiguity. Say "the staff of the local cinema" or the "programmer/program director" of it instead.

Comment: It's quite okay to qualify *cinema* as *local* - no different to, say, [*Unlike Hollywood, British cinema does not have a classical period for the gangster film*](https://www.google.com/search?q=%22british+cinema+does+not+have%22&btnG=Search+Books&tbm=bks&tbo=1). And it's just about okay to use a definite article to reference ***the** local cinema* collectively. I'm not so sure you can use this to specifically mean "the people who work in cinema locally" though. Like *local radio*, it means *those institutions as a collective whole* (or their *output*), not *the staff working there*.

Comment: All right then. It is not even clear what the intended meaning is. I edited appropriately.

Comment: Consider *Having just moved to a small rural community, I fully expect to become involved in [**the**] local politics*. If you replace *politics* by *cinema* or *church*, say, I think you'd *always* need to include the article, but it would always be understood as referring to a ***single*** cinema or church anyway.

Comment: Using @Fumble’s local radio parallel as a starting point, the meaning intended here would work if we instead say _the local radio station_, which unambiguously refers to the ‘instantiated’ establishment, rather than the concept. This raises the question of why _cinema_, which is commonly used to refer to an establishment as well (and which doesn’t really have a clearer establishment equivalent), doesn’t work in the same way. Even more parallel is _theatre_, often used in the same sense: “The local theatre aren’t even considering this movie” works just fine!

Comment: @FumbleFingers Well that's what I am trying to express, actually. A local institution in my neighbourhood, comprising one hall, one screen, some seats, and a few staff, where some old-fashioned people still go to view movies. I may be totally wrong with my terms though.

Comment: @JanusBahsJacquet Would it work with "theatre" for you? I am not sure. As I said, I looked for it, and found nothing that would support such usage.

Comment: It's tricky.  "The local cinema does not..." tends to imply that you're speaking of a single movie house.  So I would go with "The local cinema do not..." (or simply rephrase) if you mean that none of the local movie houses are willing to consider screening this flic.

Comment: @anemone Yup, works just fine for me with _theatre_, but not with _cinema_. Very odd!

Comment: @JanusBahsJacquet I'm not sure I would use the plural verb *are* there, irrespective of whether I was referring to just one local theatre, or local theatres in general. Actually with something like that I would always use 'theatres' in the plural. It would be quite a different matter were I wishing to say *Theatre in London is improving all the time*. Or *theatre isn't what it was 50 years ago*.

Comment: @WS2 I would be more likely to use a singular verb as well, but a plural one sounds okay to me. No different from “The local Indian restaurant have a lunch special on chapatti this week”, for instance. Using a plural noun would not be an option, since we’re talking about a _specific_ theatre/cinema/restaurant. If you live out in the sticks, such things are not always pluralisable, anyways.

Answer (score 2):

I think the comments here have become slightly bogged down with whether *cinema* takes a singular or a plural verb, which is not the question the OP asked.

Certainly *cinema* can exist as a collective noun e.g.

*He is a student of 1940s' cinema*. *Cinema today is very different to that of my parent's generation*. *She is desperately trying to get into cinema*. *Cinema has taken over as the principal medium for that type of drama*.

However, in the example you gave I would not immediately recognise *local cinema* as a collective noun. It sounds as if you are talking about the building at the end of the street. In that particular case I think I would use the plural *cinemas* if I wanted to get over the idea that all the cinemas in a locality had given the thumbs down to a particular film.

Comment: I may have misunderstood, but I thought the question **was** in fact specifically about whether _cinema_, as referring to the building at the end of the street, can take semantic agreement and be used with a plural verb to indicate not the building itself, but the people working in it.

Comment: @JanusBahsJacquet That was certainly how Robusto, the first commenter saw it. But I took my cue from the title, which asked if it could be used as a collective noun.

Comment: I agree that confuses the question, but I think the last paragraph in the body of the question makes it clear that that was just used for lack of a better term for a word that can take both syntactic and semantic agreement.

Comment: If it sounds as if I'm talking about the building at the end of the street, that's great! because that is what I mean. Thanks for a lot of clarification.